# Access Json objects in JavaScript / Twitter API

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API as follows:

```
...
var params = {id: 656958};
client.get('trends/place', params, function(error, tweets, response){
  if(error) throw error;
  console.log(tweets[0]); 
 });
...
```

my Console log looks like this:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVbDr.png)
[image]
Now i want to store every name with the tweet_volume in a database.
How can I access these key/value pairs?
Thanks for your help!

I tried it like this:

```
var params = {id: 656958};
client.get('trends/place', params, function(error, tweets, response){
  if(error) throw error;
  console.log(tweets[0]); 
 });
 var tweets = JSON.parse(tweets[0]);

 function getNamePair(){
  for (var key in tweets.trends) {
    var name = tweets.trends[key].name;
    var volume = jsonResponse.trends[key].tweet_volume;
         console.log(key, "Name - " + name + ", tweet_vol - "  + volume);    
     }   
 }
getNamePair();
```

But I got the error:

```
 var tweets = JSON.parse(tweets[0]);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

By using var tweets = JSON.parse(tweets);
I think i access the wrong data. 
Output in this case:

```
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

Comment: to improve your question, you could copy-paste the output of the shell to your post. You could do this so: `sudo node top_hashtag.js > ~/output.txt`. It will write the output to the file in you home dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over your `json data`.

If you are getting response as string, then you may have to `parse` it to get *JavaScript object* before iterating it. [See the updated code]. If your response is json(JavaScript object) then you can directly iterate on it.

A simple example :

```js
//if your response is string
var jsonData = "{\"trends\":[{\"name\":\"ABC\",\"tweet_volume\":101},{\"name\":\"XYZ\",\"tweet_volume\":111},{\"name\":\"PQR\",\"tweet_volume\":121}]}";

//parse string to json
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(jsonData);

function getNamePair() {
  for (var key in jsonResponse.trends) {
    var name = jsonResponse.trends[key].name;
    var volume = jsonResponse.trends[key].tweet_volume;
    console.log(key, "Name - " + name + ", tweet_vol - " + volume);
  }
}

getNamePair();
```

Store the pairs in a json ,then you can send this data to you server and there save it.

Comment: Nitpicking: JSON is the string representation. When you do `JSON.parse` it returns a JavaScript object.

Comment: Updated to fix that as well. @gcampbell

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
>
> The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array element.
>
> `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])`
>
> forEach() executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).

Makes it very simple to target only the properties you are looking for and then do something with them. Here is an example.

```js
// Your tweet data as JSON string.
let tweets = '[{"as_of":"2012-08-24T23:25:43Z","created_at":"2012-08-24T23:24:14Z","locations":[{"name":"Worldwide","woeid":1}],"trends":[{"tweet_volume":3200,"events":null,"name":"#GanaPuntosSi","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23GanaPuntosSi","url":"http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi"},{"tweet_volume":4200,"events":null,"name":"#WordsThatDescribeMe","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23WordsThatDescribeMe","url":"http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23WordsThatDescribeMe"}]}]';

let storeData = ({name, volume}) => console.log(`${name} has a tweet volume of ${volume}`);

JSON.parse(tweets)[0]["trends"].forEach( n => {
  storeData({name: n.name, volume: n.tweet_volume});
});
```